# Angular 8 Pagination with Data from Database --

Tags: datatable, pagination, angular8, angular-pagination

I am having a little trouble with this one.
Using the approach discussed in this -- https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/18/angular-8-simple-pagination-example

Use-case difference is, my data all comes from database. So I have had to use a model class and all. But, due to some problem, I am getting the same data [1st row from db] in all the rows. Let me post the code I used --

ANGULAR

1. method inside my component to get data from service class

   ```
   newsTopics: NewsTopic[];
   pageOfItems: Array<NewsTopic>;

   getAllNewsTopics() {

   this.userService.getAllTopics()
     .subscribe((data: NewsTopic[]) => {
       this.newsTopics = (data as NewsTopic[]).map((x, i) => ({ Id: (i + 1), TopicId: data[0].TopicId, TopicName: data[0].TopicName, TopicInfo: data[0].TopicInfo, IssueStartDate: data[0].IssueStartDate, IssueCloseDate: data[0].IssueCloseDate, NewsCategory_Id: 0 }));
     })
     }
   ```
2. my model class

   ```
   export class NewsTopic
   {
      Id: number;
      TopicId: string;
      TopicName: string;
      TopicInfo: string;
      IssueStartDate: Date;
      IssueCloseDate: Date;
      NewsCategory_Id: number;
   }
   ```
3. the method in service class itself

   ```
   getAllTopics(){

       var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'No-Auth': 'True' });
       return this.http.get<NewsTopic[]>(this.rootUrl + '/api/NewsTopic/GetAllNewsTopics', { headers: reqHeader });
     }
   ```
4. my html for showing the data and the pagination control

   ```
   <div class="card-body">
               <table class="table table-striped" id="newstopics_tbl">
               <thead>
                 <tr style="background:linear-gradient(50deg, #d9fcfc, #dafbde)">
                   <th>Topic ID</th>
                   <th>Topic Name</th>
                   <th>Topic Info</th>
                   <th>Start Date</th>
                 </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                 <tr *ngFor="let nt of pageOfItems">
                   <td><b>{{nt.TopicId}}</b></td>
                   <td>{{nt.TopicName}}</td>
                   <td>{{nt.TopicInfo}}</td>
                   <td>{{nt.IssueStartDate}}</td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
             </div>
             <div class="card-footer pb-0 pt-3" style="background:linear-gradient(50deg, #d9fcfc, #dafbde); margin-top:15px">
               <jw-pagination [items]="newsTopics" (changePage)="onChangePage($event)"></jw-pagination>
             </div>
   ```

My guess is, the problem lies in the getAllNewsTopics() method, where I am trying to fill and map the array of objects and assign to the variable. Something wrong there. If you see the original example from the link, they used a .fill(0) also. In my case I tried doing .fill(data[0]) however result is the same, ie. only first record, repeated multiple times.
What is the trick I am missing? Can someone just point me out.
Much needed, Thanks,

EDITS --

These are the changes->

```
getAllNewsTopics() {

    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'No-Auth': 'True' });
    return this.http.get<NewsTopic[]>(this.rootUrl + '/api/NewsTopic/GetAllNewsTopics', { headers: reqHeader })
      .subscribe((data: NewsTopic[]) => {
        this.newsTopics = data;

    });


  }
```

and

```
<div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="newstopics_tbl">
            <thead>
              <tr style="background:linear-gradient(50deg, #d9fcfc, #dafbde)">
                <th>Topic ID</th>
                <th>Topic Name</th>
                <th>Topic Info</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let nt of pageOfItems" style="cursor:pointer" (click)="NewsArticleAdd(nt)">
                <td (click)=""><b>{{nt.TopicId}}</b></td>
                <td style="color:mediumvioletred;" (click)="">{{nt.TopicName}}</td>
                <td (click)="">{{nt.TopicInfo}}</td>
                <td (click)="">{{nt.IssueStartDate}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer pb-0 pt-3" style="background:linear-gradient(50deg, #d9fcfc, #dafbde); margin-top:15px">
            <jw-pagination [items]="newsTopics" (changePage)="onChangePage($event)"></jw-pagination>
          </div>
```

That does the trick. Works as expected,

Comment: this is what output I am getting basically --> [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AH8w18DgG6wIvLtQzcv64Y4FyFXY5xNL/view?usp=sharing],

Comment: just solved this issue. pl check out the changes in the edits section of the original post.